# How to run SQL query in Powershell without Invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: powershell

I have an SQL script. I want to run it in powershell but I need to login into the database via Powershell first. I am using the SQL Authentication and not the Windows one because I need to do this from my work PC, and it doesn't have Administrator privileges. So unfortunately, I am also unable to install the sqlserver module.

I Googled it, but mostly it showed the solutions with Invoke-sqlcmd command ones or with the Windows Authentication ones. I

I know this is a stupid and probably an easy question, but I am not very good at Powershell. I was wondering if there is a way to do that without sqlserver module and by using SQL Authentication together.

UPDATE:

So basically I solved it by determining the SQL credentials into ConnectionString. This didn't work at first but I also solved it by adding SQL Adapter into the algorithm. I didn't need Admin privileges to do it. Thanks for everyone who tried to help.

Comment: For SQL to work on windows you must use an account that is valid on both local and remote machine (machine where SQL is installed).  Windows will not allow you to login using a username and password.  So you need to put the local machine a server machine in the same Group.  Than setup an account that is in the Group.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-a-group-account-in-active-directory

Comment: Can you load assembly and use .net classes like SqlConnection? `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: The SQL Adapter is part of Net library System.Data.SqlClient so an admin was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Any module can be installed by a non-admin:

```
install-module sqlserver -Scope CurrentUser
```